# tail: `/home/user_a/my_log.log' has been replaced with a remote file. giving up on this name

Tags: python, linux

I am running `tail -F` over Python fabric to tail log files of a remote process.  When the log file rotates I get the following error:

```
[user_a@server] out: tail: cannot open '/home/user_a/my_log.log' for reading: No such file or directory

[user_a@server] out: tail: '/home/user_a/my_log.log' has been replaced with a remote file. giving up on this name
```

I use the following in the fab file:

```
run('tail -F {}'.format('/home/user_a/my_log.log))
```

Any idea how to fix this?  Using `-F` should follow the name and retry but it seems to give up.

Comment: Does it work properly if you run `tail -F` manually from a shell? Are you on an embedded or otherwise minimal system (ie Busybox, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the sources](http://aqua.sfc.wide.ad.jp/~ngym/aqua-lecture/sources/coreutils-8.5/src/tail.c):

```
if (!disable_inotify && fremote (fd, pretty_name (f))){
      error (0, 0, _("%s has been replaced with a remote file. "
                     "giving up on this name"), quote (pretty_name (f)));
    }
```

`fremote` checks if the filesystem is NFS, GFS, SMB and other network filesystems

Comment: I ran into this under docker. Is BTRFS/AUFS fremote?